# I am using a newer mac, and in bash trying to write things using nano. I can not get it to display line numbers by using -c, -l,, etc?

Tags: macos, line-numbers, nano

I am using a newer mac, and in bash trying to write things using nano. I can not get it to display line numbers

I have tried using:

nano -l, nano -linenumbers, nano -c, nano --c, and more. Either I get a guide or file opens but nothing happens.

I try modifying ./nanorc files, but when I try that (I open using nano), I can't exit file and ave changes.

Comment: General questions about UNIX tools that aren't specific to software development are better suited to our sister site [UNIX.se] -- Stack Overflow is specific to programming. Emacs and vim are programmers' editors (like Helix, Neovim and other modern competitors), but that's not a specialty nano aspires to (or has ever been taken seriously at).

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking `nano -c` gives you the line numbers next to the line, but instead it tells you the current line number as a status bar above the command section. If you want line numbers, you want to do alt+shift+3 (or alt+#)